# Teambuild 2013 config transform failing to find PublishDir

Tags: c#, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a VS 2010 solution that uses config transforms like so:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<TransformXml Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.config" />
<Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.Debug.config" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" />
<Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.Release.config" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" />
<Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.Something.config" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" />
<Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.Else.config" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" />
<AspNetCompiler Condition="('$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'false') AND ('$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true')" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
<AspNetCompiler Condition="('$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false') AND ('$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true')" VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(PublishDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)" />
</Target>
```

This is in each website project (.csproj) in .sln.

When I run the v 4.0 MSBuild with a /p:PublishDir specified everything is fine. But when I run this as a Build Definition using Default template (GitTemplate.xaml) the folder for some reason resolves to `$(ProjectDir)`, not the publish location. so the transform target is trying to copy files to the folder that doesn't exist (`$(ProjectDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(ProjectName)\Web.config`).

If I manually specify the /p:PublishDir to a STATIC location on disk, the build succeeds. How can I tell the MSBuild where the PublishDir actually is?

I am happy to edit the workflow to assign a variable or something, I just don't see how its possible.

I also tried specifying relative paths (e.g. `/p:PublishDir="..\..\bin\\"`) and the team build agent variables (same as we have configured for build paths, e.g. `/p:PublishDir="D:\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionId)\bin\\"`) to no avail - it seems that the variables are not unwrapped and relative path doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this before the AfterBuild target:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir>PATH_TO_YOUR_PUBLISH_DIR</PublishDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should be able to use relative paths without problem:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir>..\..\bin\</PublishDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Remember that the path will be relative to the current project file.

If you want to override it from the command line you can add a condition like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir Condition="'$(PublishDir)'==''">PATH_TO_YOUR_PUBLISH_DIR</PublishDir> <!-- This will be the default value -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then call MsBuild with /p:PublishDir="Your_New_Path" to override the default value.

If you have a VS solution you could use something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir Condition="'$(PublishDir)'==''">$(SolutionDir)PublishDir</PublishDir> <!-- This will be the default value -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will use the directory where the solution is placed as root and will create a "PublishDir" folder there.

This will work only if you have a solution, off course you could define a default value in case there's no solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition="'$(SolutionDir)'=='' Or '$(SolutionDir)'=='*Undefined*'">Your_Default_SolutionDir</SolutionDir>
    <PublishDir Condition="'$(PublishDir)'==''">$(SolutionDir)PublishDir</PublishDir> <!-- This will be the default value -->
</PropertyGroup>
```